# How do i fix my v-brake with some part twisted?

Tags: brakes

Here's the pictures
[image: brake pic 2]
[image: pic 3]

I did a lot of searching on the youtube about the fix but couldn't find as i don't know what that part of the bike is called.Its seems to me as if i need to buy new ones moreover since that is twisted and i tried to straighten it but didn't work.
if this needs to be bought what suold i searh for to buy online and what specifiactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be to just buy new brakes. You can get them starting at about 10€/15$ which makes any attempt to repair them more expensive.

I don't know whether these tension pins can be replaced. For me, brakes are too important to try to save a few bucks on them.

Make sure the new ones are inserted completely, the pin should ideally not be visible when installed.

Comment: +1... Don't think you can fix that metal pin without breaking it. If you try to fix it it will break soon thereafter!

Comment: those are cantilever brakes so as long as the attachment is good then it will still stop the bike if the cable is pulled, though indeed I wouldn't rely on that

Comment: Better to call them V-brakes. In any case, brakes are probably the most important part of your bike that you always want working perfectly.